# Why does *struct_pointer = struct_variable not have the same behavior as struct_pointer = &struct_variable?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I'm relatively new to C++, and I'm trying to practice using -> with structs. I have this code that is supposed to print out the name and the age from the struct. I know that -> is used when the variable is a pointer, so I'm trying to declare a pointer to the struct with the following code:

```
typedef struct Person{
  string name;
  int age;
};

int main() {
  Person me;
  me.name = "name";
  me.age = 1;
  Person* me2;
  *me2 = me;
  cout << me2->name << "," << me2->age << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This code causes a segmentation fault.

However, if I change

```
*me2 = me
```

to

```
me2 = &me
```

the code works fine (prints out the name and the age).

I'm not sure why these two lines of code are not equivalent. I thought that I was allowed to change the contents of a pointer with *, but I'm not sure why that isn't working here. Can anybody help me understand this, please?

Comment: You assume `me2` is pointing to a `Person` that you can use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that the line `*me2 = me` copies the *contents* of `me` into whatever `me2` points to. By default, `me2` doesn't point to anything, which yields undefined behavior (in your case, it causes the segfault).

However, the line `me2 = &me` copies the *address* of `me` into `me2`, without dereferencing an invalid pointer. This, in fact, makes `me2` point to a valid block of memory (as it points to `me`), thus the correct behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that in C++ the asterisk (`*`) can have different meanings depending on the context in which it is used.

In one case, the `*` is used to declare a variable that is of type pointer-to-something.  When you see an `*` to the left of the name of a variable you're declaring, that's what that means.  For example:

```
Person* me;
```

Here, you're declaring a variable named `me` -- the `*` is to the left of that, and is part of the typename for `me`.  In other words, `me` is a variable of type pointer-to-`Person`

In another case, `*` is used to dereference a pointer.  To "dereference" a pointer means to follow the pointer and get the value it's pointing to.  If an `*` isn't used as part of a typename, then it's being used in this context.  An example is:

```
me = *pointerToOtherPerson;
```

Here, `pointerToOtherPerson` is (assumed to be) of type pointer-to-`Person`.  So what's happening here is `pointerToOtherPerson` is being dereferenced -- the pointer is followed to the actual `Person` object, and that object is copied in to `me` via the `=` assignment.

A related operation is taking the address of something.  This is done with the addressof-operator, `&`.  Here is an example:

```
me2 = &me;
```

Here, `me2` is a pointer, and `me` is a `Person` object (not a pointer).  By applying `&` to `me`, you take the address of `me`, and assign that address to `me2` via `=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct Person{
  string name;
  int age;
};
```

That's apparently an attempt at applying a C-ism in C++. Don't do that. The correct way to define this struct in C++ is simply:

```
struct Person{
  string name;
  int age;
};
```

Now, as for the rest code of the code...

```
  Person me;
  me.name = "name";
  me.age = 1;
  Person* me2;
```

This creates a pointer to a `Person`, the pointer's name being `me2`. However, you do not specify what it should point to! Someone else here said it is equivalent to a null pointer. That's **wrong**. Its target is unspecified, and any attempt to dereference it will be **undefined behaviour**.

The following line therefore creates trouble:

```
*me2 = me;
```

Here we go. By writing `*me`, you are trying to get a reference to something which is undefined. Undefined behaviour means, among other things, that the program is allowed to crash.

What happens next is irrelevant. Undefined behaviour has already "destroyed" your program at this point.

```
me2 = &me
```

This is something different. You do not dereference the `me2` pointer but assign it a defined value, i.e. the address of `me`.

> I thought that I was allowed to change the contents of a pointer with
>   *

Depends on what you mean by "contents of a pointer". Prepending the pointer with `*`, you simply get a reference to that which the pointer points to. And if it points to nothing or to something not defined, then the behaviour is undefined and crashes may occur.